# Bizarre blue box of death - Visual Basic - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please see the picture below.Essentially, without any action on my part, in the VBA project box in the top left, I see identical blue box spreadsheets, for every tab in the workbook. This usually is accompanied by a catastrophic failure error and I can no longer run any of my procedures.

Has anyone seen this before?

Does anyone know what I'm probably unintentionally doing to cause this?

[image]

Comment: Wow. Totally agree with @ckuhn203. That being said, I'll ask for some clarifications. What version of Excel are you using? Was this workbook created in and/or converted from an earlier version of Excel or another program? Can you provide more details as to what you're doing prior to receiving the error? Does the error have any message or code displayed? Have you attempted to export/copy the code and run it in another workbook (yours may simply be corrupted and no longer capable of being loaded correctly)? Can you post the file so we can download it and examine the workbook?

Comment: Interesting development - When I try and open the excel file, it will literally not open until I open a blank excel document (this is on windows 8 Excel 2013). If I open it first, it will load indefinitely. If I open it first AND THEN open a blank excel doc it will give me the blue box of death. However, and this is great stuff, if I open a blank doc, and then open my large file, it will open pretty quickly and there will be no issues, and no blue boxes wreaking havoc. Crazy.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm curious.

Comment: The blue box issue will only occur IF I open the spreadsheet, and it takes a while to load, and to activate it, I open a blank spreadsheet while the first is loading. Once the blank opens the 1st spreadsheet will open and then the blue boxes of death appear. Easy enough work around. Just have to be careful.